# Strange select-bug only appearing on Galaxy phones running stock internet browser

Tags: mobile, web, mobile-website

We've been designing a site for a while and while the responsiveness isn't amazing, since we had to settle for buying a WP-theme instead of designing the whole thing ourselfs, it works good on most devices. Any bugs/errors that we've found in the theme I've fixed, but this one has me stumped.

When using a basic dropdown menu on a Galaxy device using the standard Internet browser we're getting a bug. When you touch it (i.e click) it quickly flashes and then either scrolls to the top or just jumps slightly up.

The menu is used for navigating with anchors to scroll further down the page. The first option has no value and does not get called in the used javascript.

This is the HTML-markup from one of the pages, but it's the same on all  items:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap forkunskaper-714">
    <select name="forkunskaper-714" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="Nybörjare">Nybörjare</option>
        <option value="Medel">Medel</option>
        <option value="Bra">Bra</option>
        <option value="Avancerad">Avancerad</option>
     </select>
</span>
```

Things I've checked with negative results:

- Does the scripts run immediately, thinking that the first null option is viable.
- Does the scrolling anchor-script interfere with the script for the select-menu.

The last thing I can think of is some of the old scrollTo-code from the Theme interfering in some way, but since this is working on all other browsers it shouldn't be that.

Any tips about weird Galaxy-browser-specific bugs that could be helpful to my problem?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem had to do with the way the stock Samsung browsers shoots up the drop down menu. It actually resizes the window and that in turn triggered a function I had manipulating the menu you have already opened, and that caused the error in question.

So, the drop down menu (`<select>`) will in the stock Samsung browser trigger resize() in jQuery.